# I want to redirect my all traffic to http://www.mywebsite.com

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https

I want to redirect my all traffic to http://www.mywebsite.com

When someone visit https://www.mywebsite.com it will go to http://www.mywebsite.com
When someone visit https://mywebsite.com it will go to http://www.mywebsite.com
When someone visit http://www.mywebsite.com it will go to http://www.mywebsite.com
When someone visit http://mywebsite.com it will go to http://www.mywebsite.com

What i mean is i want to redirect all traffic to http://www.mywebsite.com

Here is the code which i set in .htaccess but its not working on https

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

when someone access  http://mywebsite.com the visitor will be redirected to  http://www.mywebsite.com.

Comment: Okay and when someone go to https then?

Comment: To redirect www to non-www (while using SSL)

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301]`